# While loop in python and error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to test if a number is divisible by 11 or not. Here's my code:

```
def divisible_by_11(s):
    '''Returns True if the number represented by the string s is
    divisible by 11, False otherwise.'''
    p = str(s)
    b = int(str(s)[-1])
    c = int(str(s)[-2])
    total = 0
    motal = 0
    while len(p) > 0:
              a = int(str(s)[:-2])
              b = int(str(s)[-1])
              c = int(str(s)[-2])
              total = total + b
              motal = motal + c
              s = a
              p = str(s)
    return (total-motal) % 11 ==0
```

But I am getting error

```
a = int(str(s)[:-2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of `s` ?

Comment: When doing this kind of debug, add `print` calls, like `print(s)`, `print(str(s))`, `print(str(s)[:-2])`, and so on. Then you'll be able to figure out what the error is before even asking.

Comment: The value of `s` is an empty string. The error is telling you it can't convert an empty string to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that `s` equals 11. So, line

```
a = int(str(s)[:-2])
```

will throw an error because `str(s)[:-2]` will be `""` (empty string).

Suggestion: number is divisible with 11 if sum of numbers at odd positions equals sum of numbers at even positions. Knowing this, You can write following function:

```
def divisible_by_11(s):
    odd_sum = sum([int(x) for x in s[::2]])
    even_sum = sum([int(x) for x in s[1::2]])
    return odd_sum == even_sum
```

Comment: how about `s%11 == 0` :)

Comment: Absolutely, but I figure that this task requires mathematical process for checking, not just writing a statement.

Comment: @bhansa if the number is very big then s%11 == 0 is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `int()` function should always be passed values which will have equivalent integer value

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` is raised because of the variable `s[:-2]` being a string which does not have an equivalent integer value

For example if you take `s = 11`, then the value of `str(s[:-2])` will be `''` that is empty string, which does not have an equivalent integer value